# What is | bash -

Tags: bash, dockerfile

What exactly does `| bash -` at the end of the first line of this code do in a Dockerfile?
Why the `-` at the end?

```
RUN curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | bash -
RUN yum install -y tar nodejs
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `| bash` means to pipe the output from the curl command, i.e. the downloaded bash script, as input to the `bash` command. The `-` makes bash read the script from stdin instead of from a file.

In other words, the command downloads a script and executes it with bash.

Comment: The `-` is redundant, though, since `bash` already reads from standard input in the absence of a positional argument.